# Unable to add certificates generated form String to my custom TrustManagers

Tags: java, android, x509certificate

I'm trying to create an array of TrustManagers populated with CA certificates decoded from Base64-encoded PEM Strings to pass it in SSLSocketFactory. Here is my code:

```
public static TrustManager[] getCustomTrustManagers(List<CertObject> certObjects)
{
    TrustManagerFactory tmf;
    try
    {
        tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

        if (AndroidBuild.getSdkVersion() >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
        {
            KeyStore trustStore;
            try
            {
                trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS", "BC");
                trustStore.load (null, null);
                CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                for (CertObject certObject : certObjects)
                {
                    byte[] decoded = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(certObject.getData().getBytes());
                    Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));
                    trustStore.setCertificateEntry(certObject.getName(), cert);
                }
            }
            catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException  e)
            {
                trustStore = null;
            }
            tmf.init(trustStore);
        }
        else
        {
            tmf.init((KeyStore) null);
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage);
    }

    return tmf.getTrustManagers();
}
```

The certificate is successfully generated, I see the valid instance of X509Certificate, but then it fails in

```
trustStore.setCertificateEntry(certObject.getName(), cert);
```

I have the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
  at java.util.Collections.secondaryHash(Collections.java:3405)
  at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:265)
  at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.bc.BcKeyStoreSpi.engineSetCertificateEntry(BcKeyStoreSpi.java:638)
  at java.security.KeyStore.setCertificateEntry(KeyStore.java:393)
  at com.xxx.app.core.Utils.getCustomTrustManagers(Utils.java:58)
```

Any ideas what is wrong? How should I add certificates to the keystore? `certObject.getName()` and `certObject.getData()` are both non-empty Strings. `certObject.getData()` contains PEM certificate data encoded with `Base64` without `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` Lines.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different alias looks like `certObject.getName()` is null.

```
trustStore.setCertificateEntry("MyAlias", cert);
```

MyAlias you have to replace with some dynamic String. I just used as an example.